# Laravel comparing user input plain text password with external database bcrypted password

Tags: laravel, encryption, cryptography, compare

I have 2 database tables consisting of 2 different user types.

Users and Players.

Players is with user data from in-game plugin where passwords are BCrypted. 
Users one is empty and is intended to store the user info from the Players table.

I am comparing the usernames and passwords.
The problem is that from the user input in the website get plain text password, and from the other table the passwords are already bcrypted and the Laravel bcrypt does not match the bcrypted cipher from Players table.

What are my options to compare the passwords in order to confirm that this is the user trying to log in.

In-game plugin cipher:

`$2a$10$lpVYpSJ4O6Mt03eItJeipOWR8LGHP8dgk4a09.e6BFKVoYNAgjz86`

Laravel plain text bcrypted:

```
$2y$10$yZoq3xBsfow49pL6UyGD2.5NKlmHOmfnCFc9JD5ZjDz3pf5K1XMhG
```

Both passwords are the same.

Comment: Are you using common bcrypt? You may think of using Hash class in laravel and implement the same in both sides. Just a suggestion even if you are trying bcrypt, that is correct.

Comment: I am using this one [link](https://github.com/AuthMe/AuthMeReloaded/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/xephi/authme/security/crypts/BCrypt.java) It is a open-source repository for an Authentification plugin.

Comment: bcrypt used here is different with laravel bcrypt, that is why you are getting error.

Comment: What are my options to compare the passwords?

Comment: Use common encryptors which supports PHP and Java, Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, by using a library which helped me integrate the plugin on my website.

On top of that I had to do some minor configurations in the config file of the plugin. Changing the encryption method, so it matches the one in my Laravel application (BCrypt).

Later on I found out that I don't need to decrypt the password but just compare the hashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Hash::check() function to compare plain password and hashed password.

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
   // The passwords match...
}
```

Comment: Nope didn't work. Tried comparing the bcrypted with plain text. Did not match. I know that they are the same password.